# How to stop running Timer?

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer

If I have created and started a `System.Threading.Timer` with:

```
Dim tcb As TimerCallback = New TimerCallback(AddressOf timerRoutine)
Dim t As Timer = New Timer(tcb, Nothing, DueTime, Period)
```

How do I stop it?

Would it be easier to use a `System.Timers.Timer` and call `Timer.Stop()`?

Comment: I asked google for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: The various timers are different: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx, what is "better" (or easier) depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop it by calling the method `Change` on your timer with Timeout.Infinite:
See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
t.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the Change method. Look at the remarks at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Would it be easier to use a `System.Timers.Timer` and call `Timer.Stop()`?

Comment: depending on what you're trying to acheive you should use one of the timers. you'll need to check which one you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One option is `t.Dispose()`, which will dispose of the `Timer` and therefore stop it.

If `Dispose` is called as follows it should wait for 10s for all queued timer callbacks to finish before disposing of the object:

```
Dim waitHnd As WaitHandle = New AutoResetEvent(False)
t.Dispose(waitHnd)
waitHnd.WaitOne(10000)
```